# Find discontinuities in graph network

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a layer of lines that construct a graph network like the one shown in the 1st figure.
I need to automatically find the places in my network where there are discontinuities, like the ones marked with red in the 1st figure

[image]

Zoomed in in the next figure:

[image]

I prefer using QGIS. So I have tried v.build.check toolbox, but it gives only lines with zero lengths.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the detected discontinuities? Or asked more generally: how does your desired graph network look like for this processing task?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a tough task; without network meta information like common sub-network identifiers, automated snapping is highly ambiguous to a point where it is unusable: with fractional coordinate displacements it may work, but with gaps as large as those in the example you will likely find a large portion of edge endpoints snapped erroneously. Just saying, you may need to accept facing (a likely less annoying, even) manual correction step...

Comment: That's why I ask why OP wants to *detect* these. Typically, one not only wants to snapp "snap" or otherwise fill the gaps, but typically even generalize the whole graph to a simplified, idealized connected network. While that's not easy, there are approaches for that, too.

Comment: I want to make some network analysis (such as the shortest path calculations) on that network.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Topology Checker` tool to add a rule `Must not have dangles` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. This will check all lines in the canvas or with the view extent for lines that are not connected including those end lines.

[image]

Here is an output of the plugin:

[image]

To find the tool, go to `Vector` in the Menu Toolbar → `Topology Checker`. If you could not find the tool from there, you need to activate it from the `Plugins Manager`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad. There are two issues with this solution: 1st it returns also all end points, which I don't want to include. 2nd it returns lines with overlapping, which I don't want to include as well.

Comment: @devfaz You are welcome. I know it is not a perfect solution. Another way you may try to solve the problem is to use the `v.clean` tool. Under the `Cleaning tool`, choose `snap`, and test it with some threshold values. It may give some good results.

Comment: Ahmad, I have tried v.clean (snap, with threshold equal max distance that a gap could be), but it returns almost the whole network

Comment: @devfaz I am afraid the CRS of your layer is `EPSG:4326` (WGS 84). If this is the case, then you need to choose smaller threshold values (distance values are in decimal degrees), or easier change the CRS to a meter unit like UTM with a proper zone where your lines are located. Then you can use the value you entered to cover the maximum distance again in the `v.clean` tool.

Comment: Ahmad, my CRS is 25830, which is UTM.